# Word that means impossible to build

Tags: single-word-requests

I have been looking for the word means impossible to build.
Should it be *unbuildable* or something?
Do English speakers say it that way?

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Writing advice requests are out of scope.
Questions that invite many equally valid answers are out of scope.
Word or phrase requests are out of scope, unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

As noted ***[unbuildable](http://www.yourdictionary.com/unbuildable)*** is the one word expression for "impossible to build":

> - Not buildable; that cannot be built.

(Dictionary.com)

- As a usage reference, according to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unbuildable%2Cimpossible%20to%20build%2Cnot%20buildable%2Ccannot%20be%20built%2Cnot%20able%20to%20be%20built&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunbuildable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimpossible%20to%20build%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20buildable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccan%20not%20be%20built%3B%2Cc0) expressions like "impossible to build or that cannot be built" are more commonly used than "unbuildable"